# why vtiger create new .php file in user_privilege whenever we create new user in the system

Tags: sugarcrm, vtiger, vtigercrm

I really want to know about this, let say i have around 10000 users in my company, that time it create 10000 php file in the user_privilege file. it adds lot of space in the server.

Comment: Those files store users access privileges. For example what modules they can access, whether they can edit, view, create, etc... I guess that was the most convenient or performance efficient way of storing the permissions.

Comment: Hi Ruban,Thats fine i am planning to remove this functionality and keep this at the db level because we are planning to build a sass software which can be used by more than 10000's users.

Comment: may be can use some sort of caching technique